# using articles for the words "time" and "money"

Tags: articles

I understand when I have to use "a" or "the" article with these two words. However, I don't understand clearly when I may omit any article.
Could smb explain me when I shouldn't use any article with these two words?

Comment: When it's an unspecified amount. "He owes me money." "I shall need time to do that."

Comment: The definite article is optional in contexts like *Have you got [the] money for the bus fare?* and *I don't have [the] time to cook.* You can't really pluralise ***money***, and we don't use the indefinite article *(**a/an**)* with plural nouns, but the definite article is required in ***The** times are changing*. There will be other contexts governed by other principles.